# Add Owin Pipeline Middleware after OwinStartup for new Tenant

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, ws-federation, openid-connect

I have a multi-tenant application where each tenant can define their own ClientID, Authority, etc for either WsFed or OpenIdConnect. All the tenants are registered in the OwinStartup as below:

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
 {
    List<WsFederationAuthenticationOptions> WsFedTenantOptions = BuildWsFedTenantOptionsList();
    List<OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> OpenIdConnectTenantOptions = BuildOpenIdConnectTenantOptionsList();

    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() { CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never });

    foreach (var WsFedTenantOption in WsFedTenantOptions)
        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(WsFedTenantOption);

    foreach (var OpenIdConnectTenantOption in OpenIdConnectTenantOptions)
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(OpenIdConnectTenantOption);

    ...
}
```

It switches which STS to use via `context.Authentication.Challenge(AuthenticationType)`. This is working really well.

The issue is that when a new tenant signs up, how do I access the `IAppBuilder` and add the new `AuthenticationOptions` without an Application Pool recycle?

Comment: Interesting setup. I need something like this too. Could you provide more code about the `context.Authentication.Challenge(AuthenticationType)`? How does the code know which `OpenIdConnectTenantOption` to use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IAppBuilder does not exist after Startup, it is used to build the request execution pipeline and then discarded. The pipeline was not designed to be modified after Startup.

Comment: Thanks @Tratcher. Not good news though. Is there anyway to do what I need outside of Startup? Or can the request execution pipeline be modified even though not designed to be? Can I provide the `AuthenticationOptions` at the `context.Authentication.Challenge(AuthenticationType)`?

How is a hosted application to take on new tenants wanting to use their own ADFS server for authentication without modifying pipeline?

Thanks!

Comment: These implementations were not designed for multi-tenancy.  Rather than trying to stack dozens of single-tenant components into your application I suggest you instead fork the code and build your multi-tenancy needs directly into the middleware. This should enable you to both add and remove tenants on-demand without accumulating the overhead of having so many components that inspect every request.

Comment: Thanks @Tratcher. I thought that might be the way we need to go. Great to have the confirmation. Thank you again!

Comment: Here's a workaround for inserting middleware later: https://github.com/Tratcher/MiddlewareInjector/