# Plugging a OWIN middleware component after startup

Tags: asp.net, owin, middleware, katana

How to plugin a OWIN middle-ware outside of the Startup class?

I have this OWIN middle-ware which basically sets up an authentication end point for incoming requests. During our development cycle we have noticed couple of times, the remote metadata endpoint (ADFS based) going down which causes an exception while trying to configure the middle-ware on app startup.
However, we want to let the app startup even if the middle-ware initiation fails and try to initialise the middle-ware at a later point. How do I do that without having access to the 'IAppBuilder' interface.

I am using the pre-built middle-ware in Katana for ADFS end point setup using the following method call -

```
app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
                    new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        MetadataEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint"],
                        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                        {
                            ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Most probably this fails on initialization of the middle ware because you are trying to do too much in the constructor of the middle ware. I suggest leaving the middle ware in the pipe line but defer the heavy lifting to later in it's life cycle.

Comment: I also suggest inspecting the source code for the pre-built middle-ware in Katana for ADFS to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: @Nkosi I know the cause of why the middleware is failing to initialise. However my question is in case it fails to initialise and my application continue and finish start, is there a way to plugin the middleware in the pipeline later.

Comment: No. The pipeline is established at startup via the builder. Once built you no longer have access to modify the middle-ware pipeline. [review source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin/Builder/AppBuilder.cs#L138)

Comment: [ADFS middle-ware source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory) check what is done during initialization and see if you can come up with a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OWIN infrastructure is not designed to be modified at runtime after executing the Startup code. See the [Is it possible to add WsFederationAuthenticationOptions at runtime?](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/57) discussion for more information.

If you face issues when a particular middleware fails, try wrapping it within a custom fake implementation and handle (failed?) initialization manually.

Check out the other related SO threads regarding this:

[register new middleware to OWIN pipeline at runtime without restart application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866050/)

[Add Owin Pipeline Middleware after OwinStartup for new Tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955118/)

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail.That answers my question.

Comment: It's not designed for adding middleware later, but here's sample for doing it manually: https://github.com/Tratcher/MiddlewareInjector/